# Create New User and Saving to Text File

Tags: c#, save

I am very new to C# and this is my first ever project.

I need to create a new user in my form and save his details in a normal text file(notepad).

My question is:

1. Should the program be that:
   Method 1:  first I click on the CREATE button --> Enter All Details --> Click Save Button

   Method 2:  Enter Details in Textboxes and then press the CREATE Button?
2. can any one help me with the method of creating this new user and saving it in a    notepad file?

Thanks very much.

Comment: "2) can any one help me with the method of creating this new user and saving it in a notepad file?" Unfortunately this isn't a place where people will write your code for you. However, fortunately for us there is a little website called Google lol. You should check out some tutorials and at least attempt this project. If you get an error or are stuck (After reading numerous tutorials and problem solving) you should post your issue here :) check this site out for reading and writing to text files http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx enjoy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide the 2 buttons on main page like **"Create" and "Already Exist"** then go with first method. If not then go with Second Method.

Answer (score 0):

Use method 2, it's more user friendly and what I would expect if I was using an app to fill out details.

To save it into a notepad file you can use

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\UserDetails.txt", "Name" + Environment.NewLine);
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\UserDetails.txt", "Address" + Environment.NewLine);
```

`UserDetails.txt` will then look like

```
Name
Address
```